# OpenGL: Can I create a vector with pointers to these functions?

Tags: c++, pointers, opengl, vector, glfw

I want to create a vector in the GLWindow class with pointers to these functions:

GLWindow:

```
using KeyCallback = std::function<void(KeyCode, Action, Modifier)>;
using CursorPosCallback = std::function<void(double, double)>;
using MouseCallback = std::function<void(ButtonCode, Action, Modifier, double, double>;
using ScrollCallback = std::function<void(double, double)>;
```

Is this possible, or is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: No. This are different types

Comment: These are not simply the address of a chunk of code. They are callable objects that have state of their own.

Comment: To expand the answer of "no". How do you imagine someone would use the vector to call functions with different arguments? Like, calling `v[0]` would be different from `v[1]` but vectors are supposed to be series of the same kind of things? Perhaps what you want is a struct/class with separate members for each different std::function.

Comment: You can make using Callbacks = std::vector<std::variant<KeyCallback, ,CursorPosCallback, MouseCallback, ScrollCallback>>; then these can be in same vector.